# Python: using def to define an anonymous function for use in re.sub

Tags: python, regex

I haven't been able to find an answer to whether this is legal or not. It's a function to find and replace in a string, all "variables" (which are words that start with v_). I can't use a lambda because I need more than one line for the replaceor function due to the necessity of the "if" clause.

```
def fillin(template, dictionary):
    result = re.sub(r'v_([a-z_]+)', def(match):
        variable = match.group(1)
        if not variable in dictionary:
            return match # don't replace nuthin'                                                   
        return dictionary[variable],
        Scene )
    return result
```

It gets all strings that start with a v_ in this text, then looks at the remainder of the string to get a "variable name", look that up in a dictionary and replace the string with the looked up value.

I can't use a lambda because I need an "if key in dictionary" clause in there to prevent an lookup error in the dictionary.

Is there no way to use def for anonymous functions?

Comment: `def` is a *statement*, not an *expression* - you cannot put it in the middle of the `re.sub()` call like that.  However, you can certainly have a `def` inside another `def`, so that the name you give it isn't visible anywhere outside your `fillin()` function.

Comment: You don't need can anonymous function. Just write a regular function and pass its name (without parens) as the 2nd parameter to `re.sub()`.

Comment: https://python-history.blogspot.com/2009/02/first-class-everything.html

if re.sub("replaceme", string("test"), Scene) 
works, and functions are first class objects like strings, it logically follows that functions can be defined on the spot like strings can, but well, there you go. Thanks for the help

Comment: Do you need more help or do the answers below provide enough help?

Answer (score 0):

I think this `lambda` will work for you.

```
lambda match: match if not match.group(1) in dictionary else dictionary[match.group(1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a lambda, and still keep it short if you use `dictionary.get(x.group(1), x.group())`:

```py
re.sub(r'v_([a-z_]+)', lambda x: dictionary.get(x.group(1),x.group()), text)
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/09lwXl):

```py
import re
text = "aaa v_abc v_def"
dictionary = { 'abc':'yes' }
print( re.sub(r'v_([a-z_]+)', lambda x: dictionary.get(x.group(1),x.group()), text) )
# => aaa yes v_def
```

Comment: while a lambda will work for this particular case, I think it would be useful to point to the regular way of doing complex things when lambdas starting getting awkard, which is to create a full fledged function. 
Python somewhat on purpose (and somewhat because no one could come up with a decent syntax for that, since it would mess with the indentation levels), forbids inline construction of full functions - so it has to be written using the `def` statement preceding the place it will be used.

Comment: @jsbueno The answer is that one needs a callable as the regex replacement. What you use - a lambda or a function - depends on what is more convenient. Here, a lambda is convenient enough, it is short and efficient.

Answer (score 0):

You define your function *Before* the place you are to call `re.sub', and just pass the function as a normal parameter. The "def" declaration gives the function a name - that references the function the same way an inplace "lambda" expression does.

```
def replacer(match):
   variable = match.group(1)
   if not variable in g_dictionary:
       return match # don't replace nuthin'                                                   
   return dictionary[variable]

def fillin(template, dictionary):
    global g_dictionary
    g_dictionary
    result = re.sub(r'v_([a-z_]+)', replacer, Scene)
    return result
```

The example above reassigns dictionary to a global variable, so that it can be seen in the other function. The more usual way is to define nested functions, like the in the example bellow.

As in this case you need access to "dictionary" which is a variable in the outer scope, you can define `replacer` nested inside `fillin` - that is exactlyu what happens when you define a lambda function.
:

```
def fillin(template, dictionary):

   def replacer(match):
       variable = match.group(1)
       if not variable in dictionary:
           return match # don't replace nuthin'                                                   
       return dictionary[variable]

    result = re.sub(r'v_([a-z_]+)', replacer, Scene)
    return result
```

Comment: Can't be an external function because replacer won't know what "dictionary" is. Cannot pass dictionary because the re.sub replace handler only allows one parameter.

Comment: sorry - I was in a hurry and did not even read the functions when answering earlier. The important message is that: for functions that do not fit in simple, readable expressions, you do write a full function and pass it by its name to `re.sub`. When one needs access to other variables in the scope `re.sub` is called, the usual thing is to define a nested function